# Form move events in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, form-control

My problem is the following: i have a state machine inside an app and i need to be able to pause the current states's ProcessInput function as long as the user moves the form along the screen.

I have a property called "Paused" on the state which does that and i override the OnMove event of the form so that the property is set to true when the event fires.

How do I resume the ProcessInput function of the state when the user is no longer moving the form? (To be more specific, i am looking for an event to put a "state.Paused = false" in it)

Thx in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there's a specific event you can listen for, but how about using some sort of timer based workaround?

Create a timer, reset and enable the timer every time a move event occurs. Once the timer actually fires (hasn't been reset for the duration it's set to), then set state.Paused = false.

May be a bit rudimentry, but it should work...

Answer (score 1):

You need [WM_MOVE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632631(VS.85).aspx) message, it is send when the move is done. I don't remember whether there is a handler (an event) in WinForms for it, but in worst case you can override window's WndProc and process the message manually - in "old school" C style.

Comment: i searched and i couldn't find any handler. i guess i'll have to dig a little bit further to learn how to operate with WM_MOVE. thanks, it seems like this is what i need.

Comment: .NET lacks some Win32 api features, but it's really easy to add the functionality: you can find C++ header with WM_MOVE constant and override WndProc of the window (form) class to handle this message.